# Why does my code print a repeated garbage character after my string?

Tags: string, assembly, visual-c++, x86, inline-assembly

Hi i'm new in Assembly and i've some problems with an exercise asking me to find a substring in an original string then, if found, replace it with another given string.

Example: 
original string = "This string is a string";

string to find = "string"

String substitution = "dog"

Output =" This dog is a dog"

```
void main()
{
    //Input

    char stringa[1024] = "This string is a string";

    char str1[] = "string"; // string to find

    char str2[] = "dog";    // string to replace

    // Output
    char risultato[1024]; 

    __asm
    {   

        LEA EDI, stringa
        MOV EAX, EDI             //EAX like 'i' in stringa
        LEA EDI, risultato
        MOV ECX, EDI         //ECX like 'j' in risultato

        //finding str1 in stringa
        MOV EDI, EAX
        LEA ESI, str1

 search:

        MOV BL, [ESI]       //current char of str1

        //if i'm at the end of str1 

                //mean that str1 is in stringa
        CMP BL, 0
        JZ found

        CMP[EDI], 0  //check if end of stringa
        JZ fine
        //otherwise
        CMP[EDI], BL
        JNE notfound
        INC EDI
        INC ESI
        JMP search


found:

        MOV EAX, EDI

        DEC EAX

        LEA ESI, str2   //sostitution of str1 with str2


sostituisci:

        MOV BL, [ESI]   //current char of str2

        CMP BL, 0   //checj the end of str2

        JZ continua

        //otherwise

        MOV EDI, ECX

        MOV [EDI], BL   //str2 paste in risultato
        INC ECX
        INC ESI
        JMP sostituisci //next position in str2

notfound:

        MOV EDI, EAX
        MOV ESI, ECX
        MOV BL, [EDI]
        MOV [ESI], BL
        INC ECX

continua:

        LEA ESI, str1
        INC EAX
        MOV EDI, EAX
        CMP [EDI], 0
        JNE search

fine:




    }

    // output
    printf("New string: %s\n", risultato);
}
```

I can't understand why my code doesn't work exactly.
The output is:

> New string: This dog is a dog╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠dog

instead of `New string: This dog is a dog.`

which is the reason of those symbols?

Comment: Presumably you forgot to put a `0` byte as a terminator at the right place in your `char[]` buffer to mark the end of the implicit-length C string.  In debug mode, MSVC poisons the stack with `0xCC` bytes; presumably `╠` is the character for that byte.  This makes it easier to debug your function because the error is more obvious than with random garbage which might have included some zero bytes.  Anyway, use a debugger.

Comment: you can see how you check for zero in source strings. You can find this zero, because in C and C++ when you do something like `char str2[] = "dog";`, the init-value compiled from `"dog"` is four bytes long, three bytes for letters and fourth byte is zero. So that's why your search for zero in input strings from C works. But in the new string you didn't write zero at the end = the string is not zero-terminated = it's not valid C string.

Comment: perfect, thank you. I've tried to put a 0 a the end but nothing has changed. For this reason, I thouth that there were other mistakes in my code. Probably I didn't put it in the right position.

Comment: @sof23 use memory view in debugger to see yourself content of memory in terms of individual byte values. Use this view while single-stepping over each instruction, then you can observe how your result string is built byte by byte, after each write into memory instruction. Then if you did try to add zero (probably after `fine:` label), you should see this zero byte in memory after the new string. Maybe you have other bug in logic causing you to not detect end of task correctly, or maybe you did write zero by accident into one of the source strings instead of result string,... Debugger helps :)

Comment: try to put a "\0" instead of a 0 : "This string is a string\0".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what your assembler encodes for this ambiguous `CMP [EDI], 0`. Make sure it is a byte-sized operation. Maybe you need to write something like `cmp byte ptr [edi], 0`.

---

Although your program has a messy flow it does what it needs to do with the exception of putting a zero-terminator at the end of the resulting text.

Just add this one instruction:

```
fine:
    mov byte ptr [ecx], 0
```

Please note that you can use any general purpose register for addressing memory, like I've used `[ecx]`.

1.

> ```
>     LEA EDI, stringa
>     MOV EAX, EDI         //EAX like 'i' in stringa
>     LEA EDI, risultato
>     MOV ECX, EDI         //ECX like 'j' in risultato
> ```

becomes:

```
    LEA EAX, stringa     //EAX like 'i' in stringa
    LEA ECX, risultato   //ECX like 'j' in risultato
```

2.

> ```
>     MOV EDI, ECX
>     MOV [EDI], BL   //str2 paste in risultato
>     INC ECX
> ```

becomes:

```
    MOV [ECX], BL   //str2 paste in risultato
    INC ECX
```

3.

> ```
> notfound:
>     MOV EDI, EAX
>     MOV ESI, ECX
>     MOV BL, [EDI]
>     MOV [ESI], BL
> ```

becomes:

```
notfound:
    MOV BL, [EAX]
    MOV [ECX], BL
```

---

The `LEA` instruction can do some arithmetic for you:

> ```
>     MOV EAX, EDI
>     DEC EAX
> ```

becomes:

```
    LEA EAX, [EDI-1]
```

Comment: MSVC's inline assembly encodes the ambiguous `CMP [EDI], 0` as `CMP byte ptr [EDI], 0` . If the value you try to compare is greater than what can be represented in a byte it truncates the value and it won't warn you about it.